# Should we reduce the criteria for gold badges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-bydesign

On going through the [gold badges](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=gold) available on this site, I realised that most of the gold badges have zero awarding. This may be attributed to less active participation and, thus, fewer views and fewer posts on this site daily. In response to this, can we consider reducing the criteria for gold badges on this site?

Answer (score 5):

The criteria for (gold) badges are, as far as I know, the same across all Stack Exchange sites. We, the moderators, certainly do not have any control over them. Therefore, this is not the right place to bring this issue up. Perhaps it would be more suitable on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).